# service task flow gone wrong - camunda bpmn

Tags: bpmn, camunda

I am working on the below simple logic

[image]

Problem is my service task get initiate at the time of start process itself(**very beginning - start process**). it does not depend my exclusive gateway.

it is the default behavior or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you please show you code which executed the process instance? Which Camunda Version do you use?

Comment: Also, attache your bpmn export. The behavior you are experiencing is not normal.

Comment: as per @Zelldon advice I checked with my code, I found what was the mistake. I forgot to remove one class. thanks guys!